# Calculate number of faces and dices from toss samples

Tags: probability, data-analysis

I have a sample of data. That data comes from tossing n dices with k faces and adding the values of each dice. How can I calculate k and n?

My approach:
I know that the expected value of 1 dice of k faces is
$$
E=\frac{k+1}{2}
$$
and the variance is
$$
Var=\frac{k^2-1}{12}
$$
Because each toss is independent, the variance and expected value of tossing n dices with k faces would be
$$
E=n\frac{k+1}{2},\qquad Var=n\frac{k^2-1}{12}
$$

Using this, I could calculate the mean and variance of the sample and solve the system of equations which gives me
$$
n = \frac{E^{2}}{E + 3 \, \mathit{Var}},\qquad
k = \frac{E + 6 \, \mathit{Var}}{E}
$$
The problem is that when I try with some known results, for example, 1 or 2 6 faces dice the values are incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for an "estimator" ?

Comment: Somehow yes. but my calculations are wrong, even with ideal values.

Comment: @CarlosAndrésdelValle I've calculated the case $n=2$ and $k=6$. The formulas worked as well. A reply is welcomed.

Comment: @CarlosAndrésdelValle  It works also for $n=1, k=7$ with $E(X)=Var(X)=4$

Comment: @callculus42 Thanks, I apparently had something wrong at the time when I was checking the results. THe formula is fine. Thanks.

Comment: @CarlosAndrésdelValle Nice that the formula works for you now. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any mistake. So I've made a sanity check. I´ve calculated $k$ and $n$ with your formulas for a one 6-sided die: $E=\frac{7}{2}, \, Var=\frac{35}{12}$

$$n = \frac{\frac{49}{4}}{\frac{7}{2} + 3 \cdot \frac{35}{12}}=\frac{\frac{49}{4}}{\frac{14}{4} +  \frac{35}{4}}=1$$

$$k = \frac{\frac{7}{2} + 6 \cdot \frac{35}{12} }{\frac{7}{2}}=\frac{\frac{7}{2} + \frac{35}{2} }{\frac{7}{2}}=6$$

It seems right.